# Represent repeating decimals in Rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, math

What's a good way to represent repeating decimals in the database?

Example `2.818181`, the `81` repeats

## Idea 1

Separate `2.818181` into non-repeating and repeating parts, then `non_repeat = 2.0` and `repeat = .007`

```
class Decimal < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :non_repeat, :repeat #floats

  def to_f
    to_s.to_f
  end

  def to_s
    "#{non_repeat + repeat}#{repeat.to_s.gsub(/0\./, '') * 3}" #approximation
  end

  def self.random_new
    a = rand(100)
    b = rand(100) / 100.0
    self.new(non_repeat: a, repeat: b)
  end      
end
```

## Idea 2

Use a fraction, which means turn `2.818181` into `31/11`, save two integers `31` and `11`

```
class Decimal < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :numerator, :denominator #integers

  def to_f
    numerator / denominator
  end

  def to_s
    to_f.to_s
  end

  def self.random_new
    a = rand(100)
    b = random_prime(...) # like 7, 9, 11
    self.new(numerator: a, denominator: b)
  end
end
```

For the purpose of randomly generating repeating decimals, which idea is better? Or is there another way?

Comment: I guess the question could be more clear and understandable, could you please explain a bit more?

Comment: What's a better way to model a repeating decimal? The two ways my limited intelligence came up with are (a) use 2 floats, (b) convert to a fraction and use 2 integers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second approach won't always generate a repeating decimal number, just think what happens if a is a multiple of b.

The idea of using fractions tho is the best one. You need to slightly change your approach:

- Randomly generate the integer part of your repeating number
- Generate another random integer, rapresenting the repetition
- Transform those 2 numbers into a fraction using the [usual formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeating_decimal#Converting_repeating_decimals_to_fractions)

Answer (score 0):

```
rand = rand(100)
```

3.times `{ print rand.to_s }`